# using lambda expression to set combo box data source c# windows Forms application

Tags: c#, lambda, combobox, datasource

given the following instance variable

```
        cboBankAccountId.DataSource = db.BankAccounts.Where(x => x.BankAccountId).ToList();
```

Lets assume that my table names and properties are all correct...  can somebody explain to me why this way of assigning a data source does not work with a windows form application.

However i seen in other posts that the following (and what i used in my project) works.
Now is this simply because of how a combo boxes properties are assigned in a windows form vs a web form??

```
cboBankAccountId = db.BankAccounts;
cboBankAccountId.ValueMember = "BankAccountId";
cboBankAccountId.DisplayMember = "FullName";
```

thanks...
and happy thanksgiving!

Comment: Where(x => x.BankAccountId), your back account Id is a boolean?

Comment: i see here that i need a value to compare in my expression...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A ComboBox control's data source can be a database, a Web service, or an object that can later be used to generate data-bound controls.

The problem with your code is in your lambda expression.
The extension method "Where" in your case expects a delegate of type `Func<BankAccounts, bool>`. i.e., you must pass a delegate which takes BankAccounts as input and gives bool as output which is used to filter your result.

So, if you wanted to find out BankAccounts with an Id of 1, your lambda expression would look like this:

```
cboBankAccountId.DataSource = db.BankAccounts.Where(x => x.BankAccountId == 1).ToList();
```

If you are new to Lambda Expressions, you can also translate it as:

```
cboBankAccountId.DataSource = db.BankAccounts.Where((BankAccounts x) =>
{
    return x.BankAccountId == 1;
}).ToList();
```

or, the full version:

```
public bool Filter(BankAccountId id)
{
     bool filterPassed;

     if(id == 1)
         filterPassed = true;
     else
         filterPassed = false;  

     return filterPassed;
}
cboBankAccountId.DataSource = db.BankAccounts.Where(Filter).ToList();
```

As you can see, all you need to pass to the Where method is a method which can be used for filtering out the result. Each item in the list is then run through this method and only the ones that pass the test are returned. That's how the Where extension method in LINQ works.

Comment: I get it... sorry i forgot i need a value to compare in the expression...